# After writing a script to decrease enemy health on hit as well as play an animation, I have encountered a problem where no damage is taken when hit

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have written code to ensure that once an enemy is hit, an animation plays and health is reduced, however, the code below does not reduce health once the enemy is hit but does play the animation every time. When I change this line, "

```
if (currentHealth < maxHealth&& !_isPlayingAnimation)
```

" to this, "

```
if (currentHealth > maxHealth&& !_isPlayingAnimation)
```

" health is reduced on hit but now the animation does not play at all. I'm wondering why this is happening and how I can resolve the issue. Any advice is appreciated, thanks for reading!

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyHealth : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float maxHealth;
    public float currentHealth;
    private Animator anim;
    private bool _isPlayingAnimation;
    private Animation animation;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        animation = GetComponent<Animation>();
        maxHealth = 100;
        currentHealth = 100;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (currentHealth < maxHealth&& !_isPlayingAnimation)
        {
            currentHealth = maxHealth;
            anim.SetTrigger("attacked");
            _isPlayingAnimation = true;
        }

        if (currentHealth <= 0)
            Debug.Log("Enemy is dead");

    }

    public void animationPlayIsFalse()
    {
        _isPlayingAnimation = false;
        
    }
}
```

Below is also the line from the player's script that damages the enemy,
"

```
enemyGameObject.GetComponent<EnemyHealth>().currentHealth -= damage;
```

"

Comment: do you know what is the value of damage? and what else sets the `_isPlayingAnimation`?
would be funny if something silly like damage == -10 for example. or if the `_isPlayingAnimation` is left as true by some mistake so can never get damaged.

Comment: have you tried changing the parentheses? `if (currentHealth < maxHealth && !_isPlayingAnimation)` may not be the same as `if ((currentHealth < maxHealth) && !_isPlayingAnimation)`

Comment: currentHealth is being set to maxHealth in update, undoing damage being taken.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I apologise for a question about such a simple mistake but changing the currenthealth being set to maxhealth has fixed it!